# compound linq query

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, linq, entity-framework

I have a Visual Studio 2008 C# .NET 3.5 project using MySql 5.1.53 and MySql Connector/Net 6.4.4 on Windows 7 x64.

In my application I'm looking for items with no status for either upgrades or testcases, so I query the my database as:

```
var task_query = from task in task_list_.TaskSet
                 from tc in task.TestCases
                 where
                 (task.Upgrade != null && task.Upgrade.Status.Count == 0) ||
                 tc.Status.Count == 0
                 orderby task.Order 
                 select task;
```

But, it never returns any items. If, however, I limit my query to only the upgrades and query like this:

```
var task_query = from task in task_list_.TaskSet
                 where
                 (task.Upgrade != null && task.Upgrade.Status.Count == 0)
                 orderby task.Order 
                 select task;
```

I find the upgrades that have no status. Likewise, this query:

```
var task_query = from task in task_list_.TaskSet
                 from tc in task.TestCases
                 where
                 tc.Status.Count == 0
                 orderby task.Order 
                 select task;
```

will successfully find test cases with no status.

How do I need to reform my original linq query to locate both test cases and upgrades where the status.count == 0?

Comment: Does `tc` always *have* a `Status`? What did the generated SQL look like for the first version?

Comment: @John Skeet - tc.Status is a collection of Status items. It may have 0 items in that collection. task.Upgrade.Status is likewise a collection of Status items. It will take me some time to research how to answer your second question, I will get back to you on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the two separate queries and use a union to combine them.

Answer (score 0):

```
var task_query = from task in task_list_.TaskSet 
             where 
             (task.Upgrade != null && task.Upgrade.Status.Count == 0) || 
             task.TestCases.Any(tc => tc.Status.Count == 0)
             orderby task.Order  
             select task;
```

Comment: I get an `EntityCommandExecutionException` exception with that. `"An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details."` InnerException: `"Unknown column 'Project1.TaskID' in 'where clause'"`